# Double line for <hr> tag in repeater

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm using a repeater to present multiple items in a list.

I want to separate the items by a line using a `<hr>` tag. If I omit it, there's no line; however if I add it, it displays TWO line in the browser. Anyone have a suggestion for this?

Source code of the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Lijst" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
        OnItemDataBound="Lijst_ItemDataBound" 
>
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>

<table style="width:100%">
<tr>

  <td style="width:100%">
        <asp:Label ID="Regel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  <td style="width:100%">
        <asp:Label ID="Plancode" runat="server" font-size="20px" align=right></asp:Label>
  </td>
</tr>
<hr />
</table>

</ItemTemplate>    
<FooterTemplate>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Rendering of one item:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>

  <td style="width:100%">
        <span id="MainContent_Lijst_Regel_1"></span>
  </td>
  <td style="width:100%">
        <span id="MainContent_Lijst_Plancode_1" align="right" style="font-size:20px;"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
<hr />
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you give border-bottom:1px solid black; to <tr> or <td> tag.

Comment: either using repeated image or CSS as @Navneeth suggests will solve the visual problem

Comment: border on the tr or td tags doesn't work, using it on the table still displays thee double line. I used: <table style="width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid black">

Answer (score 1):

you can use a separator template and inside it insert

---

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rp">
   <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Using this one STILL shows a double line; and besides, the second lable is displayed on a new line within the table??? EDIT - ah no the second problem was my bad. I still get the double line though.

Comment: Issue solved... ts a data issue. apparently I generated an empty table on every even row. T